# how can I add values in front of a column dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe bellow and I want to add "lap" in front of intire column 0, like "lap 1" and "lap 2"

```
  0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   ...   12   13   14   15  \
1  1  FAR  FAG  FAN  PAR  BIR  DGR  MAR  GIR  ROS  ...  HAR  HAM  MUR  CHI   
2  2  FAR  FAG  FAN  PAR  BIR  DGR  MAR  GIR  ROS  ...  HAR  HAM  MUR  CHI   
3  3  FAR  FAG  FAN  PAR  BIR  MAR  DGR  GIR  ROS  ...  HAR  HAM  MUR  CHI   
4  4  FAR  FAG  FAN  PAR  BIR  MAR  DGR  GIR  ROS  ...  HAR  HAM  MUR  CHI   
5  5  FAR  FAG  FAN  PAR  BIR  MAR  DGR  GIR  ROS  ...  HAR  HAM  MUR  CHI
```

Comment: `df[0] = 'lap ' + df[0].astype(str)` ?

Comment: `df.insert(0, 'Lap', [f"lap {i+1}" for i in range(df.shape[0])])`

Comment: both answers work very well, thank you

Answer (score 0):

use the df.insert() function

```
df.insert(0, "lap 1", ['TEMP']*5)
```

1st argument: index that you wish to insert the new column into
2nd argument: column name
3rd argument: column data